# Calcular una expresión para un número N mayor que 0

Tags: c

Debo de hacer una sumatoria con el siguiente cuerpo para un número `n` que sea mayor que 0.

El ejercicio en cuestión es el siguiente: *Σ (2-i)/(i+1)* siendo *i=1*.

A continuación les dejo el código que he intentado pero no me brinda una solución correcta:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Programa que nos calcula el sumatorio de un valor n entero mayor que 0

int main()
{

 int n, i, acumulador=0, resultado; //declaramos las variables de nuestro ejercicio, solo usaremos enteros

 printf("Programa que calcula el sumatorio para un valor entero mayor que 0, siguiendo la fórmula\n");
 printf("Introduzca a continuación el valor N del sumatorio: ");
 scanf("%d", &n);   //escanemos el valor n
 printf("---------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
 
//Implementamos la operacion y los casos que se pueden dar con dos bucles

if ( n <= 0 )
{
    printf("No has introducido un valor entero mayor que 0\n");
    exit;
}

for(i=1 ; i <= n ; i++)
{
    acumulador = (acumulador+1);
    resultado = (n * ((2-i)/(i+1)));
    
}
    printf("El valor de la productoria para el valor marcado es : %d\n", resultado);

 return 0;
 
}
```

---

Gracias y un saludo!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! C# no es lo mismo que C.. luego.. si es una sumatoria, donde la estas haciendo? si resultado es la sumatoria de todos los terminos, no deberias sumar a resultado el nuevo valor calculado? y para que usas el acumulador?

Comment: No entiendo para que es el acumulador, el resultado siempre te traerá 0. =)

Comment: Como ya te han comentad, la variable acumulador no entiendo por que la usas, a parte no entiendo la formula que has introducido dentro del for para calcular el resultado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error es que tu variable `resultado` no se está sumando en el resultado de la operación para cada bucle, de la cual se quedará pegado en `0`.

```
resultado = (n * ((2-i)/(i+1)));
```

Esto lo arreglarías reemplazando por lo siguiente:

```
resultado += (n * ((2-i)/(i+1)));
```

También la variable `acumulador` no tiene utilidad en ningún momento de tu operación. Tu código final sería el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Programa que nos calcula el sumatorio de un valor n entero mayor que 0

int main()
{

 int n, i, resultado; //declaramos las variables de nuestro ejercicio, solo usaremos enteros

 printf("Programa que calcula el sumatorio para un valor entero mayor que 0, siguiendo la fórmula\n");
 printf("Introduzca a continuación el valor N del sumatorio: ");
 scanf("%d", &n);   //escanemos el valor n
 printf("---------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
 
//Implementamos la operacion y los casos que se pueden dar con dos bucles

if ( n <= 0 )
{
    printf("No has introducido un valor entero mayor que 0\n");
    exit;
}

for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
{
    resultado += (n * ((2-i)/(i+1)));
}
    printf("El valor de la productoria para el valor marcado es : %d\n", resultado);

 return 0;
 
}
```

**Output:**

```
// Programa que calcula el sumatorio para un valor entero mayor que 0, siguiendo la fórmula
// Introduzca a continuación el valor N del sumatorio: 21
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
// El valor de la productoria para el valor marcado es : 32806
```

Comment: Buenas, he utilizado tu adaptación de código y ya mi resultado da distinto de 0, pero cuando pido datos de sumatorios de numeros pequeños como el 2 o el 1 me da valores desorbitados como el 32776. ¿Como podría solucionar esa parte? Gracias.

Comment: @HÉCTOR faltaba inicializar `resultado` en 0: `resultado = 0;` y ya quedaría el resultado.

Comment: Cierto es :), vaya error de novato! Gracias por tu ayuda